# Populating a flex 4.5 DataGrid using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

Hey so I recently started working with Flash Builder 4.5 so I am facing a lot of silly problems while building a mobile application, specially when connecting my application to a back end server.

The thing I am working on currently should update a DataGrid and this data is retrieved from a MySQL Database.

This code displays the data clearly on the browser, however the datagrid is not updated. Instead it throws the following error.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.utils::ObjectProxy@1e43bc1 to mx.collections.IList.
    at views::connectPHPHomeView/userRequest_resultHandler()[C:\Documents and Settings\s4710935\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\connectPHP\src\views\connectPHPHomeView.mxml:17]
    at views::connectPHPHomeView/__userRequest_result()[C:\Documents and Settings\s4710935\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\connectPHP\src\views\connectPHPHomeView.mxml:29]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at HTTPOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\http\HTTPService.as:993]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:451]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Can someone please guide me through this?

***EDIT***

Here is the PHP code:

```
  <?php

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialization of the sql server
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // hostname or ip of server (for local testing, localhost should work)
    $dbServer='localhost';

    // username and password to log onto db server
    $dbUser='root';
    $dbPass='password';

    // name of database
    $dbName='test';

    mysql_connect("$dbServer", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die(mysql_error());


    //Creating the table and inserting the values in it...



    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mariah_transaction_log(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      PRIMARY KEY(id),
        date DATE, 
        details VARCHAR(150),
        debit DOUBLE,
        credit DOUBLE,
        balance DOUBLE)")
    or die(mysql_error()); 


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mariah_transaction_log 
        (date, details, debit, credit, balance) VALUES('2011-08-08','Zellers','12.56','0.00','12343.54') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  


    $username = $_GET["username"];

    // $namedGreeting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_list WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    // $row = mysql_fetch_array( $namedGreeting );

    // echo "Hello ".$row['name']."!";


    $Query = "SELECT * from mariah_transaction_log"; 
    $Result = mysql_query( $Query ); 

    $Return = "<users>"; 

    while ( $User = mysql_fetch_object( $Result ) ) 
    { 
    $Return .= "<user><date>".$User->date."</date><details>". 
                $User->details."</details><debit>". 
                $User->debit."</debit><credit>".
                $User->credit."</credit><balance>".
                $User->balance."</balance></user>"; 
    } 
    $Return .= "</users>"; 
    mysql_free_result( $Result ); 
    print ($Return) 



    ?>
```

And here is the MXML and AS3 part to my code: ***NOTE*** The sample XML result was added just for simplicity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.IList;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;






            protected function callService(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var results:XML = sampleResult;
                var resultsList:XMLListCollection = results.users as XMLListCollection;
                showTransactions_dg.dataProvider = resultsList;


            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>


        <fx:XML id="sampleResult" xmlns="">
            <users>
                <user>
                    <date>2011-08-07</date>
                    <details>Camello Shop</details>
                    <debit>67.32</debit>
                    <credit>0.00</credit>
                    <balance>1233.42</balance>
                </user>

                <user>
                    <date>2011-08-07</date>
                    <details>Deposit</details>
                    <debit>0.00</debit>
                    <credit>600.00</credit>
                    <balance>1833.42</balance>
                </user>

            </users>



        </fx:XML>

        <s:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="{phpFile}"
                       method="GET" resultFormat="e4x" 
                       result="callService(event)" useProxy="false">
            <s:request xmlns="">
                <username>{username_txt.text}</username>
            </s:request>
        </s:HTTPService>


        <!-- The link to the php file -->
        <fx:String id="phpFile">http://localhost:8080/connectPHP/phpFile.php </fx:String>       

    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:TextInput id="username_txt" x="11" y="78"/>
    <s:Label x="11" y="55" text="Username"/>
    <s:Button id="getData_button" x="10" y="122" label="Done?" 
              click="userRequest.send()"/>
    <s:Label id="showName_lbl" x="13" y="173" text="show name here"/>


    <s:DataGrid id="showTransactions_dg" x="10" y="218" width="300" height="86">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="date" headerText="Date" />
                <s:GridColumn dataField="details" headerText="Details"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="debit" headerText="Debit"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="credit" headerText="Credit"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="balance" headerText="Balance"/>

            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
    <s:Label id="testLbl" x="13" y="334" width="266" height="90" text="Label"/>




</s:View>
```

Comment: Since the error occurs in Flex, you should probably include the MXML/ActionScript code in the question.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö Sorry that totally skipped my mind! I have added the MXML components now...

Answer (score 1):

In a [spark DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html) the [dataProvider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#dataProvider) must implement an [iList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html) interface. It looks like you are returning XML and storing it in a generic object.  A generic object does not support the IList interface.

Instead of binding the results of the remote call to the dataGrid's dataProvider, you should add a result handler to the HTTPService:

```
<s:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="{phpFile}"
               method="GET" resultFormat="object" useProxy="false" result="onResult(event)">
```

Then cast your data in the result Handler to something that implements IList.  I recommend an XMLListCollection in this case.

```
protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
 var resultsXML : XML = event.results as XML
 showTransactions_dg.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(resultsXML);
}
```

This code was written in the browser and may not be perfect.

Comment: hey this onResult function is showing an error....it says "Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type XML to an unrelated type XMLList". Can you explain why?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self explanatory.  XML and XMLList are not the same thing.  You'll have to convert the XML to an XMLList and then use that XMLList variable as the source for the XMLListCollection.

Comment: So I tried using this line instead of the line above: "var results:XMLList = event.result as XMLList;" Luckily it isnt showing any errors anymore but unfortunately the DataGrid does not show any values either. Like I said I am kind of new to flex, so would you mind explaining how to make this conversion from XML to XMLList please?

Comment: I use XML so rarely; I'm not sure.  I'd need a runnable sample that I can play with.

Comment: @sanjida I mean that you should create a sample that demonstrates the problem; and then post the code.  You have most of it in your question.  Once I have it up in debug mode; with a breakpoint in the result handler I could probably figure out what the issue is in a couple of minutes.  But, it'll take me an hour or so to put together a sample from scratch.

Comment: Hey I have added a couple of lines in my PHP code which will create the table and add some data in it. Unfortunately I am afraid I cannot upload the whole of the mySQL Databse since it will be against the privacy policy.

Comment: You can create fake XML with fake data and simulate the remote call by manually creating the result event and calling your result handler with that event as an argument.  Put all that in a single main application file that we can copy and paste from the browser into our code editor to test. Without that, I'm stuck. I do not care to spend hours setting up an environment in order to spend five minutes debugging the issue.

Comment: Hey sorry for getting back at you this late. I was kind of tied up with some other stuffs here. I have posted a sample XML result to my original AS3 and MXML code. Can you please help me identify the problems in it now? Sorry for all the trouble.